# SharePoint 2010 Foundation BCS Errors

Tags: bcs, error

We have an BCS issue on a Sharepoint Foundation multi-tenant farm.

Users are able to create external content types using SharePoint Designer 2010, but when they browse to the list of external data we see an error stating "Unable to display this Web Part"

In the ULS logs is see System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService, Version=14.0.0.0

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that when ECT is created using Secure Store Application ID SharePoint 2010 Foundation cannot use it, because Secure Store Service is only available in Server edition.
And though I was able to create ECT I couldn't run it.

I have a blog post about creating ECT to access SQL Server database properly here:

[Setting up External Content Type for SQL Server database using SQL Server authentication - SharePoint 2010 Foundation](http://wyldesharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/06/setting-up-external-content-type-for.html)

Comment: Nice work Slava!  I'm happy that you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

What authentication method is being set when using SPD 2010 to create the External Content Types?

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint.SE! If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. See [How do I ask questions here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) for further help.